# How to dynamically get time difference for multiple start and end times

Tags: javascript, html

I got a code from here that met my needs and it was nice till i needed to deal with more than two inputs to calculate time difference

I edited the code and it was fine for one set of inputs

```js
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    document.getElementById("start").onchange = function() {diff(start,end)};
    document.getElementById("end").onchange = function() {diff(start,end)};
    
    function diff(start, end) {
        start = document.getElementById("start").value; //to update time value in each input bar
        end = document.getElementById("end").value; //to update time value in each input bar
        start = start.split(":");
        end = end.split(":");
        var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
        var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
        var diff = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/1000/60;
        return diff;
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("diff").value = diff(start, end);
    }, 500);
```

```html
<input type="time"  id="start1" value = "08:15" >
    <input type="time" id="end1" value = "08:35"  >
    <input id="diff1">
    <br>
    <input type="time"  id="start2" value = "08:36" >
    <input type="time" id="end2" value = "08:39">
    <input id="diff2">
    <br>
    <input type="time"  id="start3" value = "08:40" >
    <input type="time" id="end3" value = "09:15">
    <input id="diff3">
    <br>
    <input type="time"  id="start4"  >
    <input type="time" id="end4" >
    <input id="diff4">
    <br>
    <input type="time"  id="start5"  >
    <input type="time" id="end5" >
    <input id="diff5">
```

my expected result was to have all diff inputs updated like the first one

Comment: Well the simple way would be to call the `diff()` function 5 times and change the parameters to use the now 5 input sets

Comment: Or you could write a loop from 1 to 5 and use the index to address the 5 sets of inputs and outputs

Comment: This is the problem with copying or being given code. Before you use it you should really study it to see what it does and how it does it

Comment: it was ok with me as i wanted just one set of inputs

Comment: Yes but now you have 5 !!

Comment: i will try to do a loop crossing my fingers to solve this

Comment: Once you have actually made a sensible attempt to write this code yourself, you are welcome to come back and ask for help if it does not quite work as you hoped. ___we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="time"  id="start1" value = "08:15" >
<input type="time" id="end1" value = "08:35"  >
<input id="diff1">
<br>
<input type="time"  id="start2" value = "08:36" >
<input type="time" id="end2" value = "08:39">
<input id="diff2">
<br>
<input type="time"  id="start3" value = "08:40" >
<input type="time" id="end3" value = "09:15">
<input id="diff3">
<br>
<input type="time"  id="start4"  value = "08:40">
<input type="time" id="end4" value = "08:40">
<input id="diff4">
<br>
<input type="time"  id="start5" value = "08:40" >
<input type="time" id="end5" value = "08:40">
<input id="diff5">
```

Here are the changes in your JS

```
    <script>

document.getElementById("end1").onchange=document.getElementById("start1").onchange = function() {
    updateDiff('start1','end1','diff1')
};

document.getElementById("end2").onchange=document.getElementById("start2").onchange = function() {
    updateDiff('start2','end2','diff2')
};
document.getElementById("end3").onchange=document.getElementById("start3").onchange = function() {
    updateDiff('start3','end3','diff3')
};
document.getElementById("end4").onchange=document.getElementById("start4").onchange = function() {
    updateDiff('start4','end4','diff4')
};
document.getElementById("end5").onchange=document.getElementById("start5").onchange = function() {
    updateDiff('start5','end5','diff5')
};


function updateDiff(start, end, diff) {
    start = document.getElementById(start).value;
    end = document.getElementById(end).value; 
    start = start.split(":");
    end = end.split(":");
    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
    document.getElementById(diff).value = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/1000/60;
}

setInterval(function(){

}, 500); 
</script>
```

here `updateDiff` is a funtion it takes 3 ids (start, end, diff) it calculate the difference and updates at the 3rd id's value, this function is reused fo all 5 cases each time passing different params

As others also mentioned, you need to understand how things are working. 
Learn about how to use function,how to pass parameter,access element by ID or class

Comment: first, Thanks a lot. i already was writing a similar code based on RiggsFolly recommendation and it is like your code. thanks again for sharing your answer

Comment: Nice to here that you are working in it. One piece of puzzle left `setInterval` this is currently empty, fix for your need